# "Interior" (like edge) detection using CIImage?

Tags: ios, ciimage

I'm trying to detect the outline of buildings in images of streetscapes. The result should be similar to what you might see on a poster, the sky is white and the buildings are filled black. This is different than typical edge detection, where it finds edges throughout the image.

I am trying to accomplish this by boosting the contrast of the image so the sky is washed out entirely. I was going to then run edge detection on the result using the CIFilter. I still think this might work, but it's slogging for me, I've never worked with image processing before.

So before I go further, does anyone know of a pre-rolled version of this?

Answer (score 2):

just stumbled across your issue.

Let me introduce at first the approach I like to choose, if I go with filters provided by Apple.

Apple has certain Graphic Tools bundled in "Graphics Tools for xCode" - please have a look for them in the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH6-BCICGCJF

If you got them, look for the "Quartz Composer".
Use this great introduction here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzComposerUserGuide/qc_tutorial/qc_tutorial.html

That's all you need to chain the filters (provided by Apple), so you get the best out of your image post processing.
I like this approach, as it is way faster than playing around with the filter parameters in code - recompile and build and run.

After you got a good result, you are happy with, translate the filters (with set parameters) into code et voila. You are all set up.

And now back to your basic idea. To have contrast enhancement and a final edge detection on the image. This is how it could look like (don't nail me on the parameters)

```
CIImage *outputImage = ciImage;
// Your Idea to enhance contrast.
CIFilter *ciColorMonochrome = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome"];
[ciColorMonochrome setValue:outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[ciColorMonochrome setValue:@(1) forKey:@"inputIntensity"];
[ciColorMonochrome setValue:[[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] forKey:@"inputColor"];// Black and white
outputImage = [ciColorMonochrome valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

// Now go on with edge detection
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
CIFilter *ciEdges = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIEdges"];
[ciEdges setValue:outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[ciEdges setValue:@(5) forKey:@"inputIntensity"];
outputImage = [ciEdges valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is how I solved this...

Start by using CIImage to turn it into a greyscale image. I used Noir because it seemed to produce a more contrasty image.

I then applied a second filter to boost the contrast to 5.

The result is an image that is purely black and white, with the black pixels being the interior.